# How to inject a Vault Secret into a Pod as an Environment Variable without overriding the Entrypoint of the Image?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I followed [this](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/injector/examples#environment-variable-example) explanation on how to inject vault secrets as environment variables into a Kubernetes container:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-deployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'web'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-config: 'secret/data/web'
        # Environment variable export template
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-config: |
          {{ with secret "secret/data/web" -}}
            export api_key="{{ .Data.data.payments_api_key }}"
          {{- end }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: web
      containers:
        - name: web
          image: alpine:latest
          command:
            ['sh', '-c']
          args:
            ['source /vault/secrets/config && <entrypoint script>']
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
```

The problem with this is approach is that it overrides the entrypoint of the container image (as pointed out [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod)), which I would like to avoid.

Is it possible to import a vault secret as an environment variable without overriding the default command and arguments of my underlying image?

A solution that reliably substitutes `<entrypoint script>` with the original entrypoint of my image without hardcoding it would also be ok.

Comment: We use the [external secrets operator](https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.0/) (using our Vault as a secret source). This populates Kubernetes Secret resources from the vault, which can then be [exposed as environment variables in pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables). This doesn't require overriding anything in the container.

Answer (score 1):

> A solution that reliably substitutes  with the
> original entrypoint of my image without hardcoding it would also be
> ok.

The linked solution you quoted is an example of such a solution.

To elaborate, let's say your image's original entrypoint is `<entrypoint script>`. According to Vault docs, you need to source secrets. The solution you shared overrides original entrypoint using `command`, it became `sh -c`. Its arguments (`args`) are specified by  `'source /vault/secrets/config && <entrypoint script>`. When the new entrypoint runs, it sources the secrets and runs the original entrypoint.

Comment: "Its arguments (args) are specified by 'source /vault/secrets/config && <entrypoint script>." Yes, but how do you substitute <entrypoint script> without hardcoding it? If the dockerfile changes, I want the value of <entrypoint script> to be adjusted without having to modify the kubernetes manifest.

Comment: if by dockerfile change you mean different entrypoint script specified in it, you'd need to modify the  `<entrypoint script>` in the manifest, right.

Comment: Any luck? I am also with the same issue? @moritz-wolf

Answer (score 0):

i have used multiple diff options third party, CRD etc you can checkout [Vault-crd](https://github.com/DaspawnW/vault-crd) Vault as source and sync to **Configmap** or **secret** but it's **base64** **encoded** not **encrypted** and CM & secret could be injected to deployment as Env vars.

**Another option**

If you want to go with **vault** and **deployment** you can use this

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-image: <Agent image>
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets: kv/<Path-of-secret>
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-secrets: |2

          {{- with secret "kv/<Path-of-secret>" -}}

          #!/bin/sh
          set -e

          {{- range $key, $value := .Data.data }}
          export {{ $key }}={{ $value }}
          {{- end }}

          exec "$@"
          {{- end }}
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: auth/<K8s cluster for auth>
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: app
```

This will create the file inside your POD.

Inside POD before your entry point call execute this file and it will set the env variables in POD.

**runapp**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f '/vault/secrets/secrets' ]; then
  source '/vault/secrets/secrets'
fi
node <path-insnide-docker>/index.js
```

In the Dockerfile **entrypoint** i uses the shell script file there is no need to mention **CMD** in **Deployment** spec.